# Python : How to know is there is a instantiation of a class in a container?

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, and I haven't figured out yet how to solve my quit simple problem. I did some research, but either I did not found or I didn't understand what to do with it... My question is :
How to know if there is an instanciation of a class in a container such as a list ; 
I want to do something like

```
if class in list :
```

I know this is a really simple question but to be honest I can't find the proper syntax to make it work :/

Comment: `class` is a keyword in Python, don't use it as an identifier.

Comment: Why do you want to find out? Python code usually follows the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) style.

Comment: Hmm  see what you mean, I meant *instanciation of this class* by class, but  thanks to you guys it works now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isinstance` built in function to test if an object is an instantiation of a *certain* `class`, and the `any` built in function to test if any of the members of an iterable match your condition:

```
>>> class A:
        pass

>>> stuff = [1,2,A()]
>>> any(isinstance(a, A) for a in stuff)
True
```

---

FYI:  **all** objects in Python are instantiations of some kind of `class` (even `class`es themselves!), so there's no point to seeing if an object in a `list` is an instantiation of *any* class, since everything in the `list` will be.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function.

```
flag = False
for obj in your_list:
    if isinstance(obj, class):
        flag = True
        break
```

Or

```
flag = any([isinstance(obj, class) for obj in your_list])
```

Comment: No need for the square brackets in you `any` call.